# Combinatorics [sandwich toppings]

Tags: combinatorics, combinations

I'm trying to figure out how to solve this excercise;

> You can order a sandwich from 5 different types of bread, you can have butter, lettuce or neither. You get to choose from 3 types of meat, and 3 types of cheeses. In how many ways can you order a sandwich?

So, I'm thinking there are 5 different ways to choose bread, 4 ways to choose butter/lettuce, 3 ways to choose meat and cheese respectively. This makes the total amount of ways to order: $5\times4\times3\times3 = 180$. Something tells me this is incorrect though…

Comment: It's unclear that having both butter and lettuce is an option. Otherwise your working looks good.

Comment: your solution is correct if the order doesn't matter, i.e. bread, topping1, topping2, topping3 go in this specific order. Essentially you have 4 consecutive slots and the options foreach are the one you've listed.

Comment: Another way to see it is by drawing a tree:put b1 in the first slot, for each choice of b1 you have 3 choices of topping1, hence 5x3, and so on

Answer (score 1):

Your logic is correct if the order of toppings doesn't matter. However, the way the problem is worded, choosing both butter and lettuce is not an option, so there are only three options: lettuce, butter, or neither.

The answer would thus be $$5\times 3\times 3\times 3=135$$